# Apple Watch App doesn't work on some devices

Tags: swift, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos-2

I'm developing an Apple Watch App. The app is based on watchOS 2.0.  During the tests some users reported to me that the watch app is stuck on an infinite loading.

Below the list on testing devices with iOS and watchOS:

- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.3 works
- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.2 works
- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.2 works
- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.1 does NOT work
- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.3 works
- watchOS 2.2.1 and iOS 9.3.3 works
- watchOS 2.0.1 and iOS 9.0.2 does NOT work
- watchOS 2.2 and iOS 9.3.2 works

This is very strange and I can't replicate this problem on my devices. How can I fix the issue?

Comment: Was it stuck multiple times on their devices? If you can't reproduce it then there's really nothing you can do. It might be a connection problem too.

Comment: The App is stuck every single time the user try to open it

Comment: So, if you can't reproduce the problem with the same OS versions you may be able to discount that as the problem. Perhaps the faults reported are not OS specific? When you say that the app is stuck, are you saying that something in your code is stuck?

Comment: The app is stuck right after the user press on the app icon on the apple watch. I guess that my code is never invoked.